# Trying to find the MacOS Framework binaries

Tags: macos, frameworks, dylib

I am wondering if anyone knows where the **real** MacOS framework binaries are located?  The traditional answer would be /System/Library/Frameworks and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks.  Yes, there is stuff in those directories, but not the actual code.

I'm aware that, on iOS, the binaries are all amalgamated into a single, memory-mapped cache file for improved performance; the cache being shared across all running apps.  I'm wondering if the same is true of recent versions of MacOS?  I could see the real binaries on High Sierra, but not recently.

So I'm guessing that (as on iOS) the individual frameworks no longer exist in discrete form; everything is in a big cache file.  But where is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in:

- `/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_{arch}` (Big Sur / Monterey)
- `/System/Cryptexes/OS/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_{arch}` (Ventura).

Comment: Thanks Art.  Coincidentally, I found a lot of discussion about the shared cache just yesterday, including source for dyld_shared_cache_util.  But I've not had time to look pick through it yet, so your direct answer was very useful.  In a way, I'm a bit surprised that Apple don't load the shared cache directly from an encrypted location on the signed system volume.  That would add an additional level of inscrutability to the mix. <g>

Comment: This is no longer valid, it seems. In Ventura (macOS 13): `ls /System/Library/dyld` -> no such file or directory.